# Draw border for NumericUpDown

Tags: c#, winforms, .net-4.0

I have an user form in application. Some fields are validated. If field has wrong value red border is drawn for this control. It is made by handling `Paint` event for this control. I extended `TextField` and `DateTimePicker` to get `Paint` event from those classes objects. I have problem with `NumericUpDown` class. It does fire `Paint` event properly but invoking

```
ControlPaint.DrawBorder(e.Graphics, eClipRectangle, Color.Red, ButtonBorderStyle.Solid);
```

does completely nothing. Any ideas or suggestions? If I won't find any way to do it, I will add a panel to hold `NumericUpDown` control and I will be changing its background colour.

Each time handler is hooked up to `Paint` event I call `control.Invalidate()` to get it repainted.

Comment: Did you solve this yet?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
public class NumericUpDownEx : NumericUpDown
{
    bool isValid = true;
    int[] validValues = new int[] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9 };

    protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnPaint(e);

        if (!isValid)
        {
            ControlPaint.DrawBorder(e.Graphics, this.ClientRectangle, Color.Red, ButtonBorderStyle.Solid);
        }
    }

    protected override void OnValueChanged(System.EventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnValueChanged(e);

        isValid = validValues.Contains((int)this.Value);
        this.Invalidate();
    }
}
```

Assuming your values are type int and not decimal. Your validity checking will probably be different but this worked for me. It draws a red border around the entire NumbericUpDown if the new value is not in the defined valid values.

The trick is to make sure you do the border painting *after* calling base.OnPaint. Otherwise the border will get drawn over. It may be better to inherit from NumericUpDown rather than assigning to its paint event because overriding the OnPaint method gives you complete control on the order of painting.

Comment: I was trying to achieve it without extending `NumericUpDown` class. Thanks for your help. My extended class doesn't contains validation method to make it more flexible. I added properties for color and border style with `Invalidate()` invoke in setters.
Actually I could make `delegate` and its instance field to let owner add validator to this control.