# How can I owner draw the "closed" portion of a ComboBox?

Tags: c#, winforms, combobox, ownerdrawn

for my current project, I need to owner draw the portion of a *ComboBox* control which is always visible to the user (not the list).
My application uses/offers light and dark mode, for which I set the back- and forecolor of each control through their different properties.
This works very well, but not for disabled *ComboBox* controls.
When I set *FlatStyle* to *FlatStyle.Flat*, I get:

- dark mode: a white border and arrow area, disabled the border is 2 pixels wide
- light mode: a white border and lightgrey arrow area, disabled there is a grey border surrounding it

If I don't set the *FlatStyle* to *FlatStyle.Flat*, the disabled *ComboBox* ist completely lightgrey with a grey arrow.

What I need is a grey border (TextBox BorderStyle *FixedSingle* like), 1px always.
Nice to have would be the arrow area in the control's background color and the arrow in the control's text color.

To eventually make it just a bit easier: I only use *DropDownStyle = ComboBoxStyle.DropDownList*.

Thanks in advance for pointing me in the right direction!

[image: This is what it looks like now]

Comment: Could you explain "owner draw" please?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/34886006/14171304 ... and you can draw everything yourself with `ComboBoxStyle.DropDownList`. BackColor, button, arrow shape and color...

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65877575/change-border-color-of-numericupdown for the NUD.

Comment: @Fredy: Owner drawn is when you catch the paint event and do the drawing on the screen yourself.

Comment: @dr.null: Thanks a lot, that's exactly what I was searching for, but never found it.